# Show that $i^{**}:Y^{**}\to X^{**}$ is an isometry

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of a normed space $X$. Let $i:Y\to X$ be the natural inclusion. Show that the adjoint operator $i^{**}:Y^{**}\to X^{**}$ is an isometry.

I have no idea, could you please give me some hints? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As $i$ is the natural inclusion, you have $\Vert i \Vert =1$.

Then if you know that for any bounded map $A \in \mathcal B(X,Y)$ between Banach spaces you have $\Vert A^* \Vert = \Vert A \Vert$, the conclusion follows
$$\Vert i^{**} \Vert = \Vert i^* \Vert = \Vert i \Vert = 1$$